# Use ::before only for the first node

Tags: html, css

I have the following text to generate :

[image]

This is my HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style5.css">
<title> Département TI </title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Département TI</h1>
    
<ul>

  <li>TC</li>
  <li>2ème année
  <ul>
      <li id="a">DSI</li>
      <li id="a">SEM</li>
      <li id="a">RSI</li>
    </ul>
  
  </li>
  <li>3ème année</li>
</ul>


</body>

</html>
```

and this is my CSS code :

```
li {list-style-type: none;}
li::before
{
content: "-*-"; 
}
```

This is what I currently get :

[image]

Comment: did you already try `element:first-child::before`?

Comment: You may use `body > ul > li::before { ... }` to select the first level of the ul. The second level will not be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `:first-child` will still target both of them, you will need to apply the `li:before` like you did, but then overwrite that rule for `ul > li > ul`. Something as following

```
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul > li::before {
  content: "-*-";
}

ul > li > ul > li:before {
  content: none;
}
```

Otherwise, you will need to wrap your `ul` tags inside something else, so you can use `:first-child` on the `ul` element itself, like this example

```
<h1>Département TI</h1>

<div>
  <ul>
    <li>TC</li>
    <li>2ème année
      <ul>
        <li id="a">DSI</li>
        <li id="a">SEM</li>
        <li id="a">RSI</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>3ème année</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

div > ul > li:before {
    content: "-*-";
}
```